# Embedded data and the _fields parameter in getEntityRecords

Tags: javascript, block-editor, rest-api, react

I'm using the following code to retrieve a list of post of a custom post type named `movie`:

```
const { posts, hasPostsResolved } = useSelect(select => {
    const query = {
        order: 'desc',
        orderby: 'date',
        status: 'publish',
        per_page: 10,
        _embed: true
    };
    return {
        posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'movie', query),
        hasPostsResolved: select('core').hasFinishedResolution('getEntityRecords', ['postType', 'movie', query]),
        }
}, []);
```

As I don't use all the retrieved fields (I just need the `id`, `title`, `meta` and `_embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] fields)`, I'd like to optimize the call adding the `_fields` parameter:

```
const { posts, hasPostsResolved } = useSelect(select => {
    const query = {
        order: 'desc',
        orderby: 'date',
        status: 'publish',
        per_page: 10,
        _embed: true,
        _fields: 'id,title,meta,_embedded',
    };
    return {
        posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'movie', query),
        hasPostsResolved: select('core').hasFinishedResolution('getEntityRecords', ['postType', 'movie', query]),
        }
}, []);
```

But when using this new code, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: o._embedded is undefined
```

It seems like the `_embedded` field in the `_fields` parameter is ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: note that while asking for only the fields you need might save on bandwidth, this type of data is highly compressable and the majority of the cost of the call is not bandwidth but database time. You may find it faster to ask for the full post which has been cached instead of bespoke couture one of a kind responses tailored to this exact specific piece of code. If you want it to be fast and scale up you want mass manufactured one size fits all replies that can be easily cached and fetched fast, asking for only what you need means the server doing extra work that client could have done trivially

Comment: also `_embedded` is only present when in requesting in embed mode, I see your JS has `_embed: true`, have you confirmed via the browser dev tools network panel that the request has the necessary embed parameter? Further reading https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/#embedding. Note that removing the `_fields` parameter has a very high chance of resolving your problem, and may even improve performance especially if you have an object cache. Also not all posts will have an `_embedded` field

Comment: also is it the code in your question that generates the type error, or is it code that isn't shared further down that uses `posts` that triggers it? If it's the latter then you need to share that code or the question isn't answerable

Comment: The code without the `_fields: 'id,title,meta,_embedded'` part doesn't throw any errors, and the `_embedded` field is present when checking the console. The code triggering the error with the `_fields` parameter is `<img src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']?.[0].source_url} />`.

Comment: then that's probably the issue, nothing to do with the code in your question. You've assumed all posts have an `_embedded` field and have not checked if this is actually the case. As a result the first post that doesn't fit the assumption triggers a type error. Not all posts have featuredmedia or embedded media, WP can't invent embedded media if none is present so you have to check for it

Comment: But, why is the same code but without the `_fields` parameter not triggering the error?

Comment: even if it should be there you should not be writing code that assumes it will be there, there are lots of other reasons things may not be present such as follow up requests to load things that haven't finished yet. You should be prepared for the post to be `null` even though it exists, and for any or all of its properties to be unfinished or undefined. Do you have filters elsewhere that change or modify the REST responses? When you inspected the network tab could you copy the request into your question and could you check that it contains the `_embedded` section directly in the response tab?